# Maximum number of even entries in a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with ***integer***  entries  such that  $\det(A)=1.$  So  what  is  the  maximum  possible  number  of  entries  of  $A$  that are  ***even*** $?$

So, I thought about  the  $3\times 3$  ***Identity***  matrix  and  wrote  the  answer $6$$($ Since $0$  is  ***even***$)$

Was it by any chance correct $?$ Or  was  it  wrong $?$

How  to prove that $?$

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're right since reducing the elements of your matrix modulo $2$, you see that you can't have three even numbers on a same line or column .

Comment: The question is a duplicate of the linked one from 5 days ago (search the site - at least the recent ones). I used that as a duplicate target, because it has an answer. However, I upvoted your question. At least you thought about the matter (unlike the other asker). You also found the correct answer!